# Templated class unknown type over multiple layers

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I've got following class Foo and FooBase:

```
class FooBase
{
public:
    virtual void A() = 0;
};

template <class T>
class Foo : public FooBase
{
public:
    virtual void A() {}
private:
    T mT;
};
```

`FooBase` is here to have a instance without needing to know the type, so I can do s.th. like this:

```
FooBase *foo = new Foo<int>();
```

Pretty standard. Now the issue: I want to bring the same thing to the next level.

So I've got the class:

```
template <class T>
class Bar : public Foo<T>
{
public:
    virtual void B() {}
};
```

And can of course use:

```
Bar<int> *bar = new Bar<int>();
```

Except I don't know the type of the template class.
So initial idea was to do the following:

```
class BarBase : public FooBase
{
public:
    virtual void B() {}
};

template <class T>
class Bar : public BarBase, Foo<T>
{
};
```

So I can do the following:

```
BarBase *bar = new Bar<int>();
```

For obvious reasons this doesn't work - the question is now: How to get s.th. like this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this issue with *virtual inheritance*. This feature assures that there is only one instance of your virtually-inherited base class when you instantiate a subclass. For your example, this would look like:

```
class FooBase
{
public:
    virtual void A() = 0;
};

template <class T>
class Foo : public virtual FooBase
//                   ^^
{
public:
    virtual void A() {}
private:
    T mT;
};

class BarBase : public virtual FooBase
//                      ^^
{
public:
    virtual void B() {}
};

template <class T>
class Bar : public BarBase, Foo<T>
{
};
```

Now you can happily create instances like you wanted:

```
BarBase *bar = new Bar<int>();
```